# Location of MAP sensor in 2011 Ford Fiesta 1.6 liter non-turbo

Tags: fiesta, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor

Can anyone tell me where the MAP sensor is on a 2011 Ford Fiesta 1.6 liter?

Answer (score 1):

The MAP (Manifold Absolute Pressure) sensor is located in the area of the throttle body assembly a little after the throttle I believe.